# Doing a calculation that references the previous value in the same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I've trying to replicate from an excel spreadsheet. It has a list of values and in the final column the formula should be if the RunningTotal = Max then the value should be 0. If the Max is equal to the max.shift(1) then the value should be the minimum of the Diff column and the and the previous value of the the MaxDraw column.

```
list = [-350,   1350,   300,    300,    -500,   -100,   -550,   1450,
-3900,  -1150,  4150,   -1900,  1700,   7750,   -3050,  -1450,  -1850,   4250]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list, columns=['Values'])
df['RunningTotal'] = df['Values'].cumsum()
df['Max'] = df['RunningTotal'].cummax()
df['Diff'] = df['RunningTotal']-df['Max']
df['MaxDraw'] = np.where(df['RunningTotal'] == df['Max'], 0,
                             np.where(df['Max'] == df['Max'].shift(1),
                                 **np.minimum(df['MaxDraw'].shift(1)**, df['Max']), np.nan))
```

The double starred code snippet is what I've tried but it looks like it can't reference a value in the row that I'm defining. I've tried doing a temporary column but i need the previous value in order to get the final result.

The expected results should match the MaxDraw column below.

```
Vales   Running Total   Max MaxDraw
-350    -350    NA      NA
1350    1000    1000    0
300     1300    1300    0
300     1600    1600    0
-500    1100    1600    -500
-100    1000    1600    -600
-550    450     1600    -1150
1450    1900    1900    0
-3900   -2000   1900    -3900
-1150   -3150   1900    -5050
4150    1000    1900    -5050
-1900   -900    1900    -5050
1700    800     1900    -5050
7750    8550    8550    0
-3050   5500    8550    -3050
-1450   4050    8550    -4500
-1850   2200    8550    -6350
4250    6450    8550    -6350
```

The excel forumula in D3 is
=IF(A3="","",IF(C3=B3,0,IF(C3=C2,MIN(B3-C3,D2))))

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been banging my head against a wall over this for quite some time now!

**EDIT:**

---

In trying to keep this vectorized and not have to use iteration - would there be a solution that would utilize np.where and say something like the value is 0 if the max column isn't equal to the max column's previous row - otherwise return a running min of the diff column until the max column changes again?

Comment: The general idea for doing this kind of thing in numpy and pandas is to use `a` and `a[:-1]` or `a[1:]` and `a` to get two arrays/series/whatever to work with.

Comment: Could you elaborate if you have some time? How would that differ than using the a.shift(1)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an explicit for loop here:

```
m = []
for i in df.index:
  if df.iloc[i,1]==df.iloc[i,2]:
      m.append(df.iloc[i,3])
  else:
     m.append(min(m[i-1],df.iloc[i,3]))

df["MAXDRAW"]=m
 df
    Values  RunningTotal   Max  Diff  MAXDRAW
0     -350          -350  -350     0        0
1     1350          1000  1000     0        0
2      300          1300  1300     0        0
3      300          1600  1600     0        0
4     -500          1100  1600  -500     -500
5     -100          1000  1600  -600     -600
6     -550           450  1600 -1150    -1150
7     1450          1900  1900     0        0
8    -3900         -2000  1900 -3900    -3900
9    -1150         -3150  1900 -5050    -5050
10    4150          1000  1900  -900    -5050
11   -1900          -900  1900 -2800    -5050
12    1700           800  1900 -1100    -5050
13    7750          8550  8550     0        0
14   -3050          5500  8550 -3050    -3050
15   -1450          4050  8550 -4500    -4500
16   -1850          2200  8550 -6350    -6350
17    4250          6450  8550 -2100    -6350
```

If you need a function for this then `itertools.accumulate` can be used.

```
list(itertools.accumulate([df.iloc[0,3]]+df.iloc[1:].values.tolist(),lambda x,y:y[3] if y[1]==y[2] else min(x,y[3])))
```

This is also related to `functools.reduce`

```
 functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+[y[3]]if y[1]==y[2] else x+[min(x[-1],y[3])],df.iloc[1:].values.tolist(),[df.iloc[0,3]])
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `itertools`.accumulate?

Comment: @DSM haha you are right. I mixed them up. Its been long since i used it. and I thought its in functools since `reduce` is in functools and the two are related.. thanks

Comment: would those be vecorized solutions? my data frame will be quite large so trying to avoid iteration if possible. Is there a way I could use np.where and say something like the value is 0 if the max column isn't equal to the max column's previous row - otherwise return a running min of the diff column until the max column changes again?

Comment: @novawaly. Since the value to be computed depends on the previous value computed, You cannot use `np.where`. I mean the previous value has to be computed first in order to compute the present value